# blazor httpClient.PostJsonAsync status code exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

When using the HTTP in Blazor client side it only works if the response is a success response, but if it is not found or bad response it gives exception and doesn't complete the code.

I want to parse the object I send in the response even if the request is not successful I mean 400 or 404, I send an object with error list so I need to get it.

It gives me error in the console that the request is not successful.

If I make the request to be (OK) then it works, but I need to send 400 status with the object "RequestResult" how I could manage this?

```
var result = await _httpClient.PostJsonAsync<RequestResult>("api/account/auth", authModel);

if (result.Successful)
{
    await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("Token", authModel.SecurityToken);
    AuthData.AuthToken= result.Token;
    ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(result.Token);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.Token);

    return result;
}

return result;
```

and this is the controller code when i change BadRequest to Ok it work

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]AuthModel model)
        {
                var res = _authManager.SignInUser(model);
                if (!res.Successful)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new RequestResult { Successful = false, Errors = new List<string>() { res?.errors } });
                }


                    return Ok(new RequestResult { Successful = true ,Token=res.access_token});
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

PostJsonAsync works this way. It will throw an exception if the content cannot be parsed.  Here is a suggested workaround:
Required using statement: `using System.Text.Json;`

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/account/auth", authModel);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //parse result as following
    using (var sr = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var parsedResult = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RecipeDetailDto>(sr);
    }
}
else
{
    //If the bad request content/body is a json object
    //parse error content
    using (var sr = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        //If the bad request content is a json
        //var parsedErrorResult = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<yourErroObjset>(sr);
    }
    //OR if the content is string
    var errorResult = await response.Content.ReadAsString();
}
```

Did not testet it, but it should give you the context how to approach this.

Comment: [Blazor uses this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Blazor/Http/src/HttpClientJsonExtensions.cs)
Blazor uses a wrapper around the browsers XMLHttpRequest (client side only)